# Letter and I dont know how to address myself to the person

Tags: correspondance

I do not know who I have to talk to. How can I address myself to the person in French when I don't know who I am writing to?

I cannot find any answer on the Internet.

Answer (score 3):

In this case I would start the letter like this:

'Madame, Monsieur,

...'

Comment: Is there any other way? Because i'm informed about the Madame, Monsieur , form. Yet it's not what i wish to use.. I know there's an other term, yet i can't actually remember. But thank you for the advice.